# WPF Window Position

Tags: c#, wpf

How I can set the position of the windows in the center of the screen in my XAML?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your Window declaration in your XAML:

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Otávio.
Also if you create a child window you can use:

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
```

But you need to remember to set the Owner property of the child window to the parent window or the child window does not center properly.

Comment: center of the screen is not center of the owner.